# Running VSCode on raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, vs-code, pi-apps

I recently saw VSCode getting official support on raspian but was wondering if it's possible to install on an Ubuntu device somehow? I would really like to live share some of my code from my windows PC to the Pi 4.

Comment: https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/Python-Development/index.html

Comment: This was an awesome solution! I never knew this was a real thing and thank you for pointing it out. I'm not sure how to make you the right answer?

Comment: @tttapa would you have an idea if it is possible for multiple people to access the Pi from anywhere?

Comment: All you need is SSH access to the Pi. If you want to be able to do that from anywhere,  you have to expose the Pi to the internet, which is not without risks. VSCode has Live Share to collaborate over the internet, but I have no idea if it works over SSH.